# continuous numbering of theorems for the whole article

Tags: numbering, theorems

In the code

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
```

what should stand in place of *section* to get continuous numbering (simply Theorem 1, Theorem 2, etc.) for the whole text?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer is "nothing".  In LaTeX `[...]` denotes an optional argument.  For `\newtheorem` when this argument is not present, these environments are number continuously throughout the document:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
  A theorem.
\end{thm}

\section{A section}
\label{sec:section}

\begin{thm}
  Another theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

The command `\newtheorem` has another commonly used optional argument.  Writing

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
```

will use the same counter for Theorems and Corrollaries, so that you get

```
Theorem 1
Theorem 2
Corollary 3
Theorem 4
```

instead of

```
Theorem 1
Theorem 2
Corollary 1
Theorem 3
```

In long documents, numbering of the former type is the most helpful to the reader.

Comment: Thank you very much. This turns out to be the default option.